# Transfer files to iPad via USB from Android

Tags: ipad, usb, file-transfer, android

I'm sure this question has been asked many times but I find it surprisingly hard to find a clear answer on the internet by searching it.

Is it possible, yes or no, to transfer files to my iPad with a USB cable from an Android device?

I have a google pixel phone, I just got a 2018 iPad, and I would like to transfer big video files between the two using a USB-C to USB-C cable. My devices are not rooted or jailbroken.

I'm sure there are other solutions like using dropbox but they seem silly compared to a USB transfer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is currently not possible using a lightning/USB port.

Apple does provide an alternative though.

See the corresponding support article: [Move from Android to iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201196)

Comment: I don't know if the contents of that link have changed, but right now it just shows how to *migrate* from an Android phone to a (new) iOS device.  The OP asked about how to transfer files from Android to an iPad, presumably without resetting the iPad first.

ETA: There is a link for "transfer content manually" but under "Photos and Videos", it only gives instructions for transferring to a Mac, not directly between mobile devices.

Comment: Also: I think this answer may no longer be accurate after the launch of iPadOS.  I have seen several Reddit threads about users either attaching their phone in PTP mode and being prompted to import photos in the iPad Photos app, or mounting their iPad as a "thumb drive", so that they can copy files onto it from their Android device. I don't have the cable to try it myself, but I'm looking at ordering one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a PC as an intemediary

- download iTunes app
- create an account to iTunes
- upload your pictures via USB-C to PC & store them to iTunes
- connect tour iPad to PC and open iTunes (if doesn’t open by itself) & sign/log in to your iTunes account
- when iPad Pro is connected via USB-C you will see at top left corner that iTunes app is recognizing your iPad.
- on left of iTunes app there is a Photos (below Videos - Music ets) upload those photos to your iPad.

On macOS it’s easier

1. you do not have to download iTunes app
2. you use your AppleID credentials to login